# file.getParents return null(Google drive)

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

Why file.getParents always return null?
How can I get id of folder where file is situated?

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

FileList result = null;
try {
    result = service.files().list().execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
List<File> files = result.getFiles();
if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("No files found.");
} else {
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        System.out.println(file.getParents());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `getParents()` method for File. The is `getParent()` method; which returns the pathname string of this abstract pathname's parent, or null if this pathname does not name a parent directory. Have alook at documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent()

Comment: @BalwinderSingh The "File" object in question is Google Drive File and not the java file object

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the latest v3 apis. Notable changes in v3 include -

> Full resources are no longer returned by default. Use the fields query
>   parameter to request specific fields to be returned. If left
>   unspecified only a subset of commonly used fields are returned.

Read - [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#notable_changes)

`service.files().list().setFields("files(id, name, parents)").execute()`

worked for me.